# How to get concatenated values of attributes?

Tags: xpath

XPath expression:

```
'.//div/concat(@id, " - ", @class)'
```

fails with an error:

```
The expression is not a legal expression.
```

in Firefox 25.0 (from a userscript).

Why, and how to fix?

For input:

```
<div id='id1' class='class1'>
  sample
</div>

<div id='id2' class='class2'>
  sample
</div>
```

I'd like to get two separate strings:

```
id1 - class1
id2 - class2
```

Comment: Give also the HTML part and expected output.. Yes your one is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox only supports XPath 1.0, but your expression requires XPath 2.0. There's no equivalent in XPath 1.0 (your expression returns a sequence of strings, which is a data type that doesn't exist in XPath 1.0).

Are you calling this XPath from XSLT or from Javascript? Either way, you will have to do the work in the host language rather than in XPath.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do as below:

**HTML**

```
<div id='foo' class='bax'>
  sample
</div>
```

**XPATH**

```
concat(//div/@id, " - ",//div/@class)
```

or

```
(//div)/concat(@id,' - ',@class)
```

**output**

```
foo - bax
```