# Scraping with scrapy - merge fields

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='conference-papers'
    start_urls = [
        'http://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2015/index.html'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for entry in response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-9"]'):
            yield{
                'type': entry.xpath('.//div[@class="h4 alert alert-info"]/text()').extract(),
                'title': entry.xpath('.//span[@class="title"]/text()').extract(),
                'authors': entry.xpath('.//span[@class="authors"]/text()').extract()
            }
```

Having the following code i want to scrape type, title and author of the every single publication listed. However when i run this i have type, in one line, titles separated with newline and authors at the end in one line.

How to join those three values together? What is the best approach to deal with this?

Here you have excerpt from the html code i want to scrap:
[image]

**BTW:** If you down vote please explain why. I am just curious.

Comment: could you just concatenate them?

Comment: But I have equal number of authors & titles however i have only three types

Comment: can you post the html of what you are scraping b/c i dont really understand clearly.

Comment: I have added a scrapy generated xml

Comment: youre scraping html, no? thats what i would like to see, if possible.

Comment: I have adden an excerpt however to see the entire thing you just need to visit the link inside a code.

Comment: and you want to put the correct TYPE with each AUTHOR and TITLE?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

you need to concatenate your values like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418858/6668185

Then you need to get the previous div for each book and get the value which would be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9857809/6668185

I will improve on this answer w/the exact solution in a sec.

**UPDATE/IMPROVEMENT**

Try this:

```
'type': entry.xpath('.//span[@class="title"]/preceding-sibling::div[@class="h4 alert alert-info"]/text()').extract()
```

I didnt test it, but I think it should work just fine.

Comment: 'type': entry.xpath('.//span[@class="title"]/preceding-sibling::div[@class="h4 alert alert-info"]/text()').extract()

In your code, try that. I think that should work. I didnt test it. You might be able to remove the class part...

Comment: Apparently does not work you still have types, titles and authors separately.

Comment: What is it giving you for the type value? It should be the correct type for the item...

Comment: Type values disappeared. In .csv i have generated i have nothing in place of type

Comment: after you get the item title...you can get the type with this:

.//span[@class="title" and contains(.,"Exploring the Manifold of Image Patches")]/../../preceding-sibling::div[@role='alert'][1]

so, first get the title, then save that value and use it to get the type...then do your yield...

i think this should work...but let me know.